# Cleaning Panel Data with Merging Firms

Tags: panel-data, data-preprocessing

Im cleaning some panel data for a regression. Subjects are firms and a substantial amount of firms have been involved in mergers. Should I just drop all firms that have ever been part of a merger? Could I drop the smaller firms from each merger and keep the bigger firms?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.